# Lotus Notes data saved as text field convert to date/time

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Old form that will be replaced by a New, and add a new view.

Old form has:

```
Expiration Date = Text field
```

New form:

```
Expiration Date = Date/Time field
```

View contains Exp. Date and Days Left.
Problem is Expiration Date of existing data is saved as a Text field. Days Left column read the Exp. Date as a text instead of Date/Time field.
So the Days Left column's output is:

```
ERROR: Incorrect data type for operator or @Function
```

Is there a way to convert all the existing date's field to date/time instead of text so the Days Left column's info will be correct? except to re-input the dates manually because the data are too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a formula agent with one line of code:

```
FIELD ExpirationDate := @TextToTime( ExpirationDate )
```

And let it run on all documents that contain fields with the wrong type.

Of course you could do some error handling in your code as well as:

```
_newVal := @TextToTime( ExpirationDate );

FIELD ExpirationDate := @If( @IsError( _newVal ); SomeFallbackValue ; _newVal )
```

Comment: `@ToTime(ExpirationDate)` might be safer if some fields already of type date/time.

Comment: In the old, old days, you would need @Command([ViewRefreshFields]) after the assignment in order to force Notes to apply the data type from the form. Otherwise, the field would still be text. The downside was that this could trigger validation formulas, and some other field might throw an error.

Comment: Hi, Thank for all your answers. I tried this code: `FIELD ExpDate := @ToTime(ExpDate);` and run it from the view and got this return on ExpDate and Days Left column: `ERROR: Unable to interpret Time or Date`